# P-NP for decision problems

Tags: np-complete

The final quiz problem asked whether the statement

*For decision problems L1, L2 in NP, if P is not NP, L1 is at least as hard as L2, and L2 is at least as hard as L1, then L1 and L2 are NP-complete*

is true or false. In fact, it seemed to me even hard to provide a counterexample for this statement, since this is intuitively a wrong assumption, but hard to prove it. I would be welcomed to know your any ideas for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that $L1$ and $L2$ are in $P$ (since $P\subset NP$).

Then both are equally hard but neither is $NP$-complete (since $P \ne NP$ by assumption).

Hence the statement is **false**.

Comment: If we choose L1 and L2 from P, how can we guarantee that L1 can be reduced to L2 and vice-versa?

Comment: @rasul_rza24 hardness usually means that there is a polynomial time reduction from one problem to the other. But this is trivial for decision problems in $P$ - just ignore the information from $L2$ and solve $L1$ in polynomial time.